# Java code for access file from remote system using camel-Jcifs library

Tags: java, apache-camel, jcifs, cifs

I am developing a java sample program to get all the file in shared folder from remote system by CIFS. For this I want to use camel-jcifs library. Can anyone suggest complete example to get the all files of shared folder by camel-jcifs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("smb://user:password@192.168.10.33/inbox?sortBy=file:name&delete=true&delay=180000&preMove=inprogress&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true").
       routeId("test")
    .to("file://c:/test/output");
  }
```